# how to convert time for different timezones

Tags: java, timezone, messaging

so i am making a messaging app but i cannot get the code done right

this is the send Button:

```
sendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                if (img == 0) {
                    if (edittext1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        Numberrr++;
                        mm = new HashMap<>();
                        mm.put("username", get_name);
                        mm.put("pfp", get_pfp);
                        mm.put("messages", edittext1.getText().toString().trim());
                        mm.put("user_uid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        mm.put("number", String.valueOf((long)(Numberrr)));
                        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        mm.put("time", new SimpleDateFormat("E hh:mm s").format(cal.getTime()));
                        ch.push().updateChildren(mm);
                        mm.clear();
                        edittext1.setText("");
                        lastText.edit().putString("Lasttext", String.valueOf((long)(Numberrr))).commit();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    store.child(imgName).putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(imgPath))).addOnFailureListener(_store_failure_listener).addOnProgressListener(_store_upload_progress_listener).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Task<Uri> then(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                            return store.child(imgName).getDownloadUrl();
                        }
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(_store_upload_success_listener);
                    progressbar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sendbutton.setEnabled(false);
                    edittext1.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

and this is part of the code for the ListView:

```
            LayoutInflater _inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View _view = _v;
            if (_view == null) {
                _view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.messgebubble, null);
            }

            final LinearLayout time = _view.findViewById(R.id.time);
            final TextView textview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            final LinearLayout linear4 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear4);
            final TextView timetext = _view.findViewById(R.id.timetext);
            final LinearLayout left = _view.findViewById(R.id.left);
            final LinearLayout linear1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
            final de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView circleimageview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.circleimageview1);
            final TextView message = _view.findViewById(R.id.message);
            final ImageView imageview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
            final TextView SystemText = _view.findViewById(R.id.systemtext);
            final LinearLayout system = _view.findViewById(R.id.system);
//This is to set the time on text view 
            timetext.setText(new Sim("MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(_data.get((int)_position).get("time").toString()));
//end
```

so im trying to get messages to display the right time for messages while in different timezone

e.g. if someone is in (UTC+1) but the message is from (UTC+5)and the message was sent at 17:35(UTC+5) it would show 17:35 but it should be showing 14:35... as you can tell this will cause a lot of problems in code also.

edit: a revision

Comment: It's really not clear what your question is.  But the `Calendar` class is notoriously bad at timezone handling.  You should think about using the classes in the `java.time` package, because they let you clearly distinguish between a moment in time (`Instant`), a local expression of what date/time it is (`LocalDateTime`), a date/time in a timezone (`ZonedDateTime`), and a date/time that's a known number of hours ahead or behind UTC (`OffsetDateTime`).  Start using those classes, instead of the old obsolete ones.

Comment: sorry for the rough explication. ill revise it.

Comment: and ill look into that, thank you

Comment: There are be quite some lines of code that don’t seem to pertain to the problem you are asking about. Could you instead put a [mre] example in your question?

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. If this is for lower version Android, use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Did you remember to serach before posintg? What did you find? Did it seem to help in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But likely these points will help you:

- Never use the legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc. They are *terrible*. Use only the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.
- To track a moment, a specific point on the timeline, do so “in UTC” (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC), using the `java.time.Instant` class.
- To serialize a moment textually for data storage or data exchange, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Usually best to do so in UTC, using `Instant#toString` and `Instant.parse`.

Here is some brief code. But search to learn more. All this has been covered many many times   already on Stack Overflow.

## Capture current moment

Use `java.time.Instant` to represent a moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC. 
String s = instant.toString() ;    // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

## Parse

Here we parse text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2022-04-19T15:30:14.348767Z" ) ;
```

## Adjust into time zone

For presentation to the user, you may want to adjust to a particular time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Generate text

### Standard format

To generate text in standard format, simply call `toString`.

> instant.toString(): 2022-04-19T15:30:14.348767Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2022-04-19T09:30:14.348767-06:00[America/Edmonton]

Actually that last one is an wise extension of the standard format, appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

### Localized format

To generate text in a localized format, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`.

```java
FormatStyle style = FormatStyle.SHORT ;
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US or new Locale( "fr" , "MA" ) (French in Morocco), etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( style ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/pO6oiq).

> output: 22-04-19 09 h 30

You can of course specify a custom format via `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`. ([Search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern&t=osx&ia=web) to learn more.) But automatically localizing might make your life simpler.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this, and yes I did search, it took me 3 hours yesterday trying to figure this out. But I guess I didnt word it correctly

Comment: Okay so this kinda answer my question. So its good but not really good for a messaging app. It converts it into a nice local date but that's it. I would also like to format it to fit app better e.g. 12/2 8:36pm or something

Comment: @austinwhiteted Reread the last line of my Answer. And [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime&t=osx&ia=web) to learn more. Maybe I can add a quick example.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Sorry for that